# Multiple geom_hline in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to include two horizontal lines using geom_hline in ggplot. The scale on my graph runs from 0 to 20,000 and I would like to have single lines at 400 and 17,000.

`?geom_hline` gives examples for single lines ( `geom_hline(yintercept = 20)` ) and for multiple lines ( `(geom_hline(yintercept = 1:5)` ). But the latter will give a line at every point between the two numbers.

So `geom_hline(yintercept = 400: 17000)` creates lines with intercepts at `400, 401, 402` etc. And `geom_hline(yintercept = 400, 17000)` only produces a single line for the first number. I'm sure there's something apart from `:` and `,` I need to try, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: do you want `geom_line(yintercept = c(400, 17000))`?

Comment: Hi @RichardTelford, I tried adding your suggestion but I get `Error: Unknown parameters: yintercept` and no lines at all.

Comment: dont forget the h?! Try geom_hline(yintercept=c(400,17000)) ?

Comment: Nice point @JanSila ! but then I get a different response `mapping: yintercept = yintercept 
geom_hline: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity ` Not an error but no graph either...

Comment: I simulated some **'rnorm x<-rnorm(500); d<-data.frame("x"=x,"den"=dnorm(x))'** and plot them as a line, it works fine..is your data in data.frame? Does this work for you if you simulate the values?

ggplot(d,aes(x,den))+geom_line()+geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.1,0.2))

Comment: Thanks @JanSila, I had missed out a `+`, your answer worked fine. Would you or @RichardTelford like to write it as an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks, hope Richard doesnt mind, he's got much more reps :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I simulated some random data and plot them as a line. It works fine. Are your data in a `data.frame`?

Does the following code work for you?

```
x <- rnorm(500)
d <- data.frame("x" = x, "den" = dnorm(x))
ggplot(d, aes(x, den)) + geom_line() + geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.1,0.2))
```

Comment: To supplement the suggestions and answers from @Jan and @Richard, it was `geom_hline(yintercept = c(LOWER.LINE, UPPER.LINE))` which solved my issue. Thanks for the help!